# what is this "concurrency" killing my performance (visual 2012)

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, c++11, concurrency

I'm working on a processing plugin that needs to run fast (performance is critical - at least to some extents-)
I have an engine that does the processing part and a shell around it that handles:

- communications
- messages
- GUI
- logs
- calling the engine

Here is the analysis that I have on visual studio:
[image]

The percents are relative to the samples on a process which is the host.

- This host does very few things and is exclusively using 12.19% of the samples.
- My shell is using 50% exclusively
- the engine (called by the shell) exclusively is using 12.8%.

As you can see the processing part in my shell (BaseProcessor::process and all included function calls) is around 15% which is just 3% more than the engine alone. it means that the overhead of my "shell" is not too big.

But my "shell" is spending more time in functions about concurrency (exclusively and inclusively).
These functions are part of **threadproxymain** code from VS CRT code.

**what is this `concurrency::details` thing, how can I solve this**

I'm using std::atomic and futures a bit, and I have sleeps in working threads AFAIK.

Thank you for your suggestions!

**[EDIT]**

The problem, after several tests (with much more samples to improve presision), happened to be in a code calling this that was not shown in this view but the exclusive samples/module helped me to find which DLL was using all this CPU.
After that, I found out using the function details view that the call was made from CLogBuffers (which is in this view 5% inclusive)

thank you for pointing my error

Comment: You sorted the list rather poorly before taking the screenshot, nothing is taking more than a few %.  Click on the "Exclusive Samples" column to get the expensive code listed at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sharing only a picture of the data, and is not relevant data. All one can tell from looking at the function list sorted by Inclusive is that some funcitons sit at the head of the stack (like Dispatch, ThreadProxyMain etc) and will be in *every* stack, hence the high **inclusive** count but very low **exclusive** count. Nothing new here, always to be expected, does not indicate any problem.

The few functions that seem to do *any* work are: GetNextVirtualProcess, FindVirtualProcessor, StealLocalRunnable and SearchCacheLocal. One can only guess, having nothing but a picture to look at, but It looks like your own code doesn't really *do* anything and the only thing left to capture in the perf data is when the code is yielding and such.

There are many more views in perf analysys (butterfly view is great example) that would help pinpointing toward a *problem* (if one really exists). As things stand, I really don't see any perf issue in the picture you posted. Is also a very small sample, at 1000 samples is basically irrelevant. Did you capture your process under serious load, for sufficient time, with sufficient resolution?

Comment: Hello, Yes indeed it is by inclusive time, but exclusive does not help me much more as it is not precise (depth) enough. About the sampling time, I tested under the load I expect it will be used. however, I can make the test time longer (here several minutes). **I don't know this view on visual, where is it?**

Comment: Butterfly view is the view you get when you double click a funciton in the function list view (the one in picture). You pick the top Exclusive ones and the butterfly view shows you function samples, callees and callers.

Comment: Indeed I found the problem, after several tests, the issue was in a code that was calling this, The exclusive samples/module showed in what module to look for the problem. Even if from there it was hidden in the details